# Affinity Key in Aerospike

Tags: aerospike

In the aerospike documentation, it is mentioned that aerospike has 4096 logical partitions and each key is hashed and eventually mapped to any of the partitions between 1 to 4096, which determines in which node the data for that key should be stored.

However if we have two keys "A" and "AB" and we want to store them in the same node, is there a way?

In Redis it can be achieved by making the keys as "A" and "{A}B" that will make sure that the key "{A}B" will go to a node where "A" is hashed and stored.

In Apache Ignite, same can be done using "AffinityKey".

Does a similar idea exist in Aerospike?

Thanks

Comment: Aerospike doesn't have such feature at this point. What is the use case behind this requirement?

Comment: lets say i have a huge table for global schools, in which the primary key is school id which is random, but it has columns like country, school name, etc etc...all my queries always have country field in them atleast and some other optional fields. So, if i have a table which is distributed across 10 partitions, and the data is spread across randomly, for any query like "select * from schools where country = india and foo = bar", i will need to fire 10 queries and its time will be dictated by the slowest query. Instead if i create 'country' as the affinity key, data will be split countrywise.

Comment: adding to above comment, and i will be able to get all the data using only one query in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Aerospike was designed as a distributed database. Redis was designed to run on a single node, and lacks concepts such as [data distribution](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/data-distribution.html), [clustering](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/clustering.html), replication, failover, at least natively. I'm aware that you can use various application-side shenanigans to make it into an ad-hoc cluster.

Don't worry about the implementation details of Aerospike's data distribution. Those happen automatically between the client and cluster, and don't require you to do anything on the application side. Instead, think about your access patterns.

First, your Aerospike cluster will make sure the data is evenly distributed. Because work is directly proportional to data, you should make sure the nodes are homogeneous. You can then expect multi-node operations to wrap up in roughly the same amount of time on each node.

You can create a [secondary index](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/secondary-index.html) on the fields that you'll be [querying](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/query.html) often to enhance the speed of the query. Release 3.12 adds [predicate filtering](http://aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html), allowing you to create more complex query predicates on top of the initial secondary index based filter (also see the Java client's [PredExp](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PredExp.html) class).

If you don't want to use secondary indexes (there are several valid reasons), you can create your own lookup using external records. In a [set](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/data-model.html#sets) called *country-school* you can have a [record](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/data-model.html#records) for each country (keys such as 'india', 'luxembourg') with the value being a [list](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list.html) containing the IDs of the schools in that country. You can get the list with a single get (or a batch-get if it's several records, such as india-1, india-2, ... , india-9999), then use the results to compose a [batch-get](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/batch.html) operation for the schools. Batch reads return results in the ordered you asked so you can get a large batch, check whether the last element is null, and if not get another batch.

```
('ns1', 'country-school', 'us-california') => [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11, .. ]
```

Similarly, you can create permutations such as *country-state-city*, (example, us-california-oakland) with smaller lists. This costs some extra space, but gives you faster ([key-value](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/single.html) based) retrieval without spending memory on secondary indexes.

```
('ns1', 'country-school', 'us-california-oakland') => [ 1, 5, 42, .. ]
```